# What is a good way to create a variable in JsRender?

Tags: javascript, variables, jsrender

In a JsRender template, blocks can create variables, so I could write this:

```
{{if true ~myVariable=myExpensiveFunction()}}
  {{:~myVariable}} {{:~myVariable}}
{{/if}}
```

However, the bogus `if` is annoying. Is there a better way?

Comment: can you just make a more semantic custom tag than _if_?

Comment: Hm, I guess. I hoped I had overlooked an obvious, built-in solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can initialize `myVariable` outside the template, then you can make it a [helper variable](http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers), and pass it in:

```
var html = myTmpl.render(data, {myVariable:myExpensiveFunction()});
```

If you need to initialize in a specific template/data context then as you say, you can use [contextual parameters](http://www.jsviews.com/#contextualparams), which are scoped to any template block. Use the tag that wraps that context.

If the context is is top-level in a template, then:

- either this is top-level data and you can pass in a helper as above
- or it is a 'partial' template rendered from anothor (layout) template, using `{{someTag tmpl=.../}}`, in which case you can set up your contextual parameter from the calling tag in the other template
- or else it is rendering against an array

For that last case you can use `{{include}}`:

```
{{include ~myVariable=myExpensiveFunction()}}
  {{:~myVariable}} {{:~myVariable}}
{{/include}}
```

or you can call with `noIteration` set to true:

```
var html = myTmpl.render(data, [helpers,] true);
```

and then wrap in `{{for}}`:

```
{{for ~myVariable=myExpensiveFunction()}}
  {{:~myVariable}} {{:~myVariable}}
{{/for}}
```

EDIT:

In your particular case, based on your comments added below, you need to initialize in the context of an item block within a `{{for someArray}}` - in order to get the item data.

(Actually your item block is a 'partial' template called using `{{for someArray tmpl=...}}`, but the basic problem is the same).

In this scenario you will indeed need to add an `{{include}}` wrapper, at top-level (for you) or within the `{{for}}` if not doing template composition.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really helpful answer. My case is a template rendered from another template. I'm not quite sure how to follow your advice here. The template is called like: `{^{for results tmpl="#resultListItemTemplate" /}}`, the problem is that the function call needs the `#data` INSIDE this called template as a parameter, and I don't know how to access it in the `for` statement; is this possible? With `{^{for results tmpl="#resultListItemTemplate" ~myVar=myFunc(#data)/}}`, `#data` still refers to the data outside of the for loop, right? – If this is not possible, I'm going for `include` :)

Comment: Ah yes, if your context needs the item data, you will need to wrap in `{{include}}`. I updated my reply to include that scenario...